# iText. How to adjust header width (C#)?

Tags: c#, itext

I need adjust header width of the table created with iText. Column width set with `table.SetWidths(lstMaxCount.ToArray())` method, that is standard way to do this, but is there way to adjust column header width to avoid break line? 
Here is how it look like now:
[image]

Comment: You are already defining the width of every column. Can you explain how the width of the header of these columns could be different from the width of the columns? I fear that I don't understand the question. Also: what is `lstMaxCount`?

Comment: Sometime header text width are larger then column with and this splitting line. How to avoid this? lstMaxCount this is array of columns width

Comment: If you defined column widths that are too small for the column headers, why don't you make the column widths bigger? I'm sorry, but your question still doesn't make sense to me. It's as if you deliberately choose 750 cl bottles and then ask: how can I put 1 liter into 750 cl bottles? The answer is simple: take 1-liter bottles to start with!

Comment: Probably the op should add a sketch to his question illustrating his desired result...

Comment: @BrunoLowagie, problem is that I'm not familiar with iText API at all and must fix another developer code, so I can suppose approximately how this working. Is there any way to compare column width to header width?

Comment: The column width = the header width. If you want a different header width, change the column width. That is: change the values returned by `lstMaxCount.ToArray()`. Or reduce the font size of the headers.

Comment: The text width = column width , you can try a property of the table cell i.e pdfcell.setwrap = false; which may fit in a single row.

Comment: @andrey.shedko I don't understand why you added a bounty to this question. I have answered the question in a comment: change the values returned by `lstMaxCount.ToArray()`. I don't think any one else can provide a better answer (the fact that the question remains unanswered proves this). If you don't understand my answer, you should rephrase the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one solution would be to make the header display on 2 rows for the columns with small width.

My suggestion would be to split `PackageNumber` column name in two words, and put a new line inside:

```
"Package" + Environment.NewLine + "Number"
```

Make your header height enough to fit 2 lines of text in it.

Set the PdfPCell's property `NoWrap = false`

There are also another options to wrap a text on multiple lines. You can use `Paragraphs` and `Chunks`. You can take a look here: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=35[enter link description here](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=35)